# How to delete mongoose array item not knowing its parent id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my data:

```js
{
    _id: 'unknown',
    playHistory: [
        {
            _playHistoryId: ObjectId('5f564893f6b66f3d94dbf19e')
        },
        {
            _playHistoryId: ObjectId('5f564893f6b66f3d94dbf19f')
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to delete an item in the array of playHistory if the _playerHistoryId matches.
example

```js
this.collection.updateOne(
      {},
      {
        $pull: { playHistory: { _playHistoryId: new ObjectId('5f564893f6b66f3d94dbf19e') } }
      }
)
```

It won't delete.
Any advice?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It requires to define query condition when we update array field using `updateOne()`,
- don't use `new` keyword before object id,

```
this.collection.updateOne(
      { "playHistory._playHistoryId": ObjectId('5f564893f6b66f3d94dbf19e') },
      {
          $pull: { playHistory: { _playHistoryId: ObjectId('5f564893f6b66f3d94dbf19e') } }
      }
)
```